# How to make a dynamically sized image gallery using CSS

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, image-gallery

I am creating my first webpage with Ruby on Rails. I am new to styling in CSS and I am trying to make an image gallery with square images in three columns centered on the page. I want the images to be dynamically resized when the window changes, but retain their position and proportional size.

The images all have different aspect ratios, so I am forcing them into squares with the width and height attributes. My first suspicion was to have an unordered list on each line with three list items. I tried using the max-width and height attributes to dynamically resize the images, but there are two problems with this solution:

1. This changes the image sizes to their original aspect ratios
2. The list items wrap when the window gets small enough, rather than the pictures changing size.

Here's the associated html.erb and css I have so far:

```
.gallery ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.gallery li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.gallery li img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

<h2>Gallery</h2>
<div class="gallery">
  <% num_columns = 3 %>
  <% @image_paths.each_index {|i| %>
    <% if i % num_columns == 0 %>
      <ul>
    <% end %>
        <li>
        <%= image_tag @image_paths[i], size: "500x500" %>
        </li>
    <% if i % num_columns == num_columns - 1 || i == @image_paths.length - 1 %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can suggest that; If you have images with different aspect ratios and you have put them side by side, you need to put them in a div with the same aspect ratio as a background image. This the a way out, when you are using them as a background image you have to place them perfectly visit here: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/